# mvc) I wanna get list of player in my listplayer view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```html
namespace Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model
{
    public class Repository
    {
        private static List<Player> addplayers = new List<Player>();

        public static IEnumerable<Player> Players
        {
            get
            {
                return addplayers;
            }
        }

        public static void AddPlayer(Player player)
        {
            addplayers.Add(player);
        }
    }
}
```

I have an error >> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model.Player', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model.Player]'.

I want to add player name and ID in listplayer view but I can't.
[image: When I]

I want to fix my code like if player choose "Yes, I will", the player name and ID will be added to listplayer.

Here is my "manage" code (join page)

```html
@model Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model.Player
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Join us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-cheerful fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand disabled" href="/Home/Index">
                <img src="~/images/logo.png" width="50" height="50" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" id="btnNavigation"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="color:#feb0cc"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="text-align:center">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/club">More Information</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Manage">Join</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="album py-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                    <h1>Join us!</h1>
                    <hr />
                    <form class="p-a-l" asp-action="RsvpForm" method="Post">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Name">Your name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Email">Your ID</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Phone">Your Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Phone" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="WillJoin">Will you join?</label>
                            <select class="form-control" asp-for="WillAttend">
                                <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                                <option value="true">Yes, I want</option>
                                <option value="false">No, I don't want</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="container">
        <p>&copy; 2020 Seoyoung - Centennial College - COMP229.</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Homecontroller code

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model;

namespace Seoyoung_K_301000618.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Manage(Player player)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Repository.AddPlayer(player);
                return View("ListPlayer", player);               
               
            }

            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Manage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult ListPlayer()
        {
            return View(Repository.Players.Where(r => r.WillJoin == true));
        }


        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult Club()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And, Here is my listplayer code (the player information will be added here)

```html
@model IEnumerable<Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model.Player>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>List of Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-cheerful fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand disabled" href="/Home/Index">
                <img src="~/images/logo.png" width="50" height="50" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" id="btnNavigation"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="color:#feb0cc"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="text-align:center">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/club">More Information</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Manage">Join</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="album py-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
                    <h1>Here is the list of player</h1>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>ID</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model.Player addplayers in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@addplayers.Name</td>
                            <td>@addplayers.Id</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="container">
        <p>&copy; 2020 Seoyoung - Centennial College - COMP229.</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The listplayer view looks like that

[image]

```html
namespace Seoyoung_K_301000618.Model
{
    public class Repository
    {
        private static List<Player> addplayers = new List<Player>();

        public static IEnumerable<Player> Players
        {
            get
            {
                return addplayers;
            }
        }

        public static void AddPlayer(Player player)
        {
            addplayers.Add(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your ```HomeController.Manage``` method you are returning ```return View("ListPlayer", player);```, but you should return a list of players: ```return View("ListPlayer", Repository.Players.Where(r => r.WillJoin == true));```

Comment: @JoelWiklund it can work but he has not saved changes so it will not reflect anywhere

Comment: @JoelWiklund I solved the error, but player information wasn't added

Comment: Then you need to show how your ```Repository.AddPlayer``` method looks like. If you're using ```Entity Framework```, you need to use the method ```.SaveChanges()``` after any adding, deleting or updates of data. Preferably in your ```AddPlayer``` method. Read more [here](https://entityframework.net/save-changes).

Comment: @JoelWiklund I don't use Entity Framework, I add my Repository code

Comment: This Repository won't persist between calls. You need to save your data to a permanent storage like a file or to a database (recommended) or save your data to a temporary storage like a session or a cache. Read how to save to a database [here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/mvc-articles/insert-update-delete-in-asp-net-mvc-5-without-entity-framework.php).

Answer (score 0):

**You made a mistake here**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
 Repository.AddPlayer(player);
 //you have return single player object                   
 return View("ListPlayer", player);               

}
```

**Right Code**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  Repository.AddPlayer(player);
  Repository.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("ListPlayer");               
}
```

Comment: @JoelWiklund I am sure as per my code review skill I can say that this code refers to Entity framework